# empty array in angular-schema-form

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm using angular-schema-form in my project and trying to add an empty array in my model.

I expected that array type schema form will not contain any items but it actually pushed one object in my array and showed it in from.

How can I init form with no items in array?

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller as ctr">
  <form sf-schema="ctr.schema" sf-form="ctr.form" sf-model="ctr.model"></form>
  {{ctr.model.comments}} - Where this object come from? This array was empty. Is it possible to keep it empty on load?
</div>
```

**js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['schemaForm'])
  .controller("Controller", function() {
    this.schema = {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Comment",
      "properties": {
        "comments": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "title": "Name",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "comment": {
                "title": "Comment",
                "type": "string",
                "maxLength": 20,
                "validationMessage": "Don't be greedy!"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    this.form = [{
      "key": "comments",
      "items": [
        "comments[]"
      ]
    }];

    this.model = {
      comments: [] // Empty array defined
    };
  });
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9237/)

Comment: But if I what to init the array with 2 empty objecs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are looking for is `startEmpty: true` this will avoid pre-populating the array with an object.

[Angular Schema Form: Array Documentation](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#array)

The pre-population is defaulted to ensure that the form fields within an array are available when the form loads. The `startEmpty: true` value can override this behaviour.

Comment: But if I what to init the array with 2 empty objecs?